# knockout binding objects

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I spent some time try to figure out why a binding does not work without success the ‘(not working binding on click)’ in the html section.
I have a simple list of Players; when clicking on one of them I should see the binded name changing in the bottom page:
1) the player name binded with vm.selectedPlayerName is shown properly
2) the player name binded with vm.selectedPlayer.name() is shown properly only at page load time and never on the click event, even if the console log shows a proper change in the selectedPlayer object.
I would like to make the 2) working to avoid to redefine properties in the view model.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var my = {}; //my namespace
    // Player
    my.Player = function () {
        this.name = ko.observable("");
    };

    // The ViewModel
    my.vm = function () {
        var
        players = ko.observableArray([]),
        selectedPlayer = ko.observable(),
        selectedPlayerName = ko.observable(""),

        goToDetails = function (aPlayer) {
            my.vm.selectedPlayer = aPlayer;
            my.vm.selectedPlayerName(my.vm.selectedPlayer.name());
            console.log("goToDetails: ", my.vm.selectedPlayerName());
        },

        loadPlayers = function () {
            my.vm.players.push(new my.Player().name("Player1"));
            my.vm.players.push(new my.Player().name("Player2"));
            my.vm.players.push(new my.Player().name("Player3"));
            my.vm.selectedPlayer = my.vm.players()[0];
            my.vm.selectedPlayerName(my.vm.selectedPlayer.name());
        };

        return {
            // Data
            players: players,
            selectedPlayer: selectedPlayer,
            selectedPlayerName: selectedPlayerName,
            // Other
            loadPlayers: loadPlayers,
            goToDetails: goToDetails,
        };
    }();

    my.vm.loadPlayers();
    ko.applyBindings(my.vm);
    });
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: players">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name, click: $root.goToDetails"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p>
    Selected player (working binding on click): <span data-bind='text:  $root.selectedPlayerName'></span>
    <br />
    Selected player (not working binding on click): <span data-bind='text:  selectedPlayer.name()'></span>
</p>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not assigning something to the SelectedPlayer observable:

```
 goToDetails = function (aPlayer) {
       my.vm.selectedPlayer = aPlayer;
       ...
  },
```

should be:

```
 goToDetails = function (aPlayer) {
       my.vm.selectedPlayer(aPlayer);
       ....
  },
```

Remember, an observable is technically a FUNCTION. When you assign it via the assignment operator you're overwriting it as a function, to replace it with an object, which only gets processed at page load in the knockout model.